# html 2 yaml tool

Tags: html, cakephp, migration, yaml, data-migration

We need to put some html as part of a yaml migration file for CakePHP. Is there anything out there that people use for this?

Thanks.

Comment: HTML to yaml? What would that look like? Can you show a before/after example please?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out you can tell yaml not to actually parse a value by using the | character. This is all I needed.

Thanks..